# Что лучше использовать для вывода сообщения зависящего от состояния: условный рендеринг или вычислять значение?

Tags: vue.js

Задача простая, если товар на складе, должно быть сообщение "В наличии", и наоборот.
Можно это делать через v-if вот так.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    inStock: true
  }
})
```

```css
<style>
 span {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
 }
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
    <span v-if="inStock">В наличии</span>
   <span v-else>Нет в наличии</span>
  </div>
```

А можно через наблюдение за свойством и переопределением значения, отображаемого внутри блока. Так:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "В наличии",
    inStock: true
  },
  watch: {
    inStock: function () {
   if (this.inStock) {
    this.message = "В магазине";
   }
   else {
    this.message = "Нет в наличии";
   }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change: function () {
      this.inStock = this.inStock ? false:true;
    }
  }
  
})
```

```css
span {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
 }
  button {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <span>{{message}}</span>
    <button @click="change">сменить состояние</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

С кнопкой пришлось добавить чтобы показать как меняется значение.
Какой подход более правильный.
В 1-м смущает, что надо добавлять или убирать узел DOM(как я понимаю, span не соответствующий условию, удаляется из DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что заменим строку `this.inStock = this.inStock ? false:true;` на `this.inStock = !this.inStock;`
И первый подход гораздо менее многословный и более понятный.
Да, узел DOM удаляется и добавляется. Чтобы просто скрывать юзайте **v-show**.
Кстати можете убрать **watch** и сделать **message** вычисляемым свойством, возвращая нужный текст в зависимости от **this.inStock**.
Тогда темплейт будет как во втором варианте.